# 11month old baby fall

Tags: infant

My baby of 11month  old fell down from a bed of 2 foot high and had a swollen forehead,i have applied hot balm on the affected area and he fell asleep.what do I look out for when he wakes up to ensure he doesn't have any internal injury?

Comment: I'm definitely not a medical professional but letting people with a head injury fall asleep can be dangerous! Please be sure to monitor your baby closely!

Comment: To reduce swelling, use a cold pack, not heat. Protect the skin from direct cold. If you are concerned, wake the  baby and see if he is more fretful than usual. My concern would be concussion, but I know very little about babies, so if you are worried, take him to a doctor or call and ask a clinic if he should come in.

Comment: @Catija its OK to let people sleep after a head injury http://www.brainline.org/content/2012/07/is-it-true-that-you-should-keep-someone-awake-who-has-sustained-a-.html it can even be beneficial. Medical professionals may wake them up, but that is because they want to find things out, not because they don’t want the patient to sleep.

Comment: Medical questions are off topic here; no one on the internet can reassure you as well or as accurately as a doctor examining your child in person.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for a doctor. Take your baby to the hospital. It's clearly enough an injury for you to be concerned, so unless you are a medical professional, better safe than sorry.